# how to adjust motion blur to background in cycles blender

Tags: motion-capture, motion-blur

[image]Creating video using image sequence. I want to express the speed using motion blur. For example, add strong motion blurs to wheels and backgrounds and add a little less to the main object. What can I do?

Comment: And I'm also curious about the direction of motion blur. Does this apply automatically? Or can I control it?

Comment: You have pre-rendered images and want to add motion blur to them as a post effect?

Comment: Yes. Additionally, I added a photo. Also, can you make the camera view automatically apply because it is an animation?

Comment: In this case, is motionblr more effective?

Comment: What you want to do is to either recreate the scene with the background, a moving car, and the car's wheels turning, and render that using motion blur enabled in render settings, or use a 2D software to cut the car out to a separate layer, and cut the wheels out to separate layers, and apply a motion blur to the background, the car (if you want to simulate the camera movement in relation to the car) and a circular blur to the wheels. Doing this in Blender would be unnecessarily hard, so what your question is missing is why you want to do it in Blender.